# Phantom strong tags in wordpress

Tags: html

[image: ss]

So as you can see, there are some strong tags that wordpress is obviously putting in on its own (of course because I never put them there) and appending it to my elements. I've also found two strong tags on the hero as well, but they didn't contain anything in them like these ones.
What's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

You most likely haven't correctly closed a `<strong>` tag somewhere. This is the browser's attempt to resolve that problem.

If you look at the raw HTML source by right clicking then *View Page Source* (*not* Inspect Element) you should be able to see if there's a `<strong>` tag with a missing or misspelled `</strong>` tag.

The HTML structure you see in the Inspector tab is not the actual HTML that was received from the server, it's a document tree reconstructed by the browser *based* on that HTML. If you have errors in the original HTML, like missing closing tags, then the browser will be forced to find a way to fix that error so that it can create a valid DOM. This can lead to things like phantom tags.

Comment: Another thing you could try is to search in the theme directory for the `<strong>` string, to find where it could originate.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the CSS panel in Developer Tools for those elements to see what CSS file (from your theme, from elsewhere) or even if the strong tag is an in-line tag.

The source of the CSS is what will help you. Either the theme (for sure if in-line) or a plugin is causing the unwanted tag. Using Developer Tools and inspecting the element will give you (and us) more clues.   Edit your question if you find additional clues.

Comment: CSS cannot add `<strong>` elements to a page.

Comment: I read the question as saying there was some 'strong' elements (or 'bold'). And it is possible to have a css rule for 'strong' (see example https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_strong.asp ), although perhaps deprecated. The OP didn't make clear that there was the actual 'strong' element in the page source. So I suggested that he look via Developer Tools to get more information. If it is the 'strong' tag (not a CSS rule), the Dev Tools will help determine that. It could also be some script that is applying the 'strong' tag via the DOM element. So Dev Tools is helpful in this case.